# How to access json property laravel

Tags: json, laravel

I have an object of JSON data in my laravel application. When I display that variable in blade

```
{{$permissions}}
```

I get the following

[image: Image of one row of data]

How would I access the role ID?

Thanks

Comment: MachNamara,  Pls post your data?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a object, you just do

```
`$json->roles[0]->id`
```

if it is a string, you must decode it first so you do

```
$json = json_decode($string);
```

and then you do step 1

Comment: Actually it will never be a JSON over PHP. Replace your first sentence by "If it's an Object, you just do" instead.